# IP scan then do certain job and play MP3 only once

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

I have the following  code here. What I want to do is I want to script to scan my ip address then do certain job.

My problem is the MP3 is always repeating every 30 seconds even if I did not turn off my phone WIFI which is carrying the IP of the hostname.

I'd like the MP3 to only play once after the script found the IP but the scan will continue scanning.

Is that possible? Any help will be very much appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc):
        import os
        hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
                print(hostname, 'is up!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
                os.system("omxplayer -o local ../music/jarvis_on.mp3 1")
        else:
                print(hostname, 'is down!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_off.py 1")
        sc.enter(160, 1, do_something, (sc,))
s.enter(30, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want to run certain behaviors when the availability of the IP adderss you're scanning for changes. That is, you want to do one action when it becomes available (after having been down) and a different action when it goes down (after having been available). You don't want to do anything if it keeps doing the same thing it was doing before.

This requires that you make your function access some kind of `state` variable. A local variable won't work because you call the function repeatedly from the scheduler (rather than writing your own loop). I think there are three reasonable alternatives.

The simplest (from the perspective of how much your current code will need to change) is to use a global variable. Something like this will work:

```
import os, sys
import sched, time

state = None

def do_something(sc):
        global state    # global statement is required since we write to the global state
        hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0 and state != "up":
                state = "up"
                print(hostname, 'is up!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
                os.system("omxplayer -o local ../music/jarvis_on.mp3 1")
        elif state != "down":
                state = "down"
                print(hostname, 'is down!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_off.py 1")
        sc.enter(160, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(30, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Global variables are often considered bad programming practice, since they clutter up the global namespace, especially in a situation like this when you won't be accessing that `state` variable from any other code. It's not really a big deal for a small script like this, but it's a bad idea to do this in any more complicated code.

The next alternative uses a closure to hold the state variable. A closure is the namespace of an outer function that an inner function can access. To write to a variable in a closure, you'll need to use a `nonlocal` statement, just like the `global` statement in the previous version of the code (this is only available in Python 3, which it looks like you're using):

```
import os, sys
import sched, time

def do_something_factory():
    state = None  # state is a local variable in the factory function's namespace

    def do_something(sc):
        nonlocal state    # nonlocal statement lets us write to the outer scope
        hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0 and state != "up":
                state = "up"
                print(hostname, 'is up!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
                os.system("omxplayer -o local ../music/jarvis_on.mp3 1")
        elif state != "down":
                state = "down"
                print(hostname, 'is down!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_off.py 1")
        sc.enter(160, 1, do_something, (sc,))
    return do_something # return inner function to caller

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(30, 1, do_something_factory(), (s,))  # call factory function here!
s.run()
```

The final approach is to use a `class` to contain the function (as a method). The state will be stored in an instance variable, accessed via `self`. The main script code will create the object and then pass the bound method to the scheduler. You could probably move some or all of that code into the class if you wanted to, but I'll leave the design more or less the same for now.

```
import os, sys
import sched, time

class Doer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None

    def do_something(self, sc):
        hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0 and self.state != "up":
                self.state = "up"
                print(hostname, 'is up!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
                os.system("omxplayer -o local ../music/jarvis_on.mp3 1")
        elif self.state != "down":
                self.state = "down"
                print(hostname, 'is down!')
                os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_off.py 1")
        sc.enter(160, 1, self.do_something, (sc,))

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
d = Doer()
s.enter(30, 1, d.do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: Hi @Blckknght Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately, I am running the python version 2.7.3.  I have tried your simplest answer above though with no error but still mp3 is looping... Will it hurt my system if i will upgrade my python version? 

The two or your answers has an error as expected because of my python version. error is "NameError: global name 'do_something' is not defined
"

Comment: Yeah, Python 2 doesn't allow the `nonlocal` statement used in the middle solution. The last version had a typo, if you add `self` to the `sc.enter` call in the method it should work (I've edited the code above). I have no idea why you were still getting loops on the first version though. It should only call the `omxplayer` command once at the start, then once every time the system comes back up after being down. What does it print out?